# Using org-screenshot.el in windows (emacs)

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, org-mode

I am using ergoemacs(emacs) on windows. I would like to use org-screenshot(org-screenshot.el) to capture the screenshot. I have used cygwin-mount to use cygwin. Unfortunately the "import %f" does not work. I believe it works only when x-server is on. Let me know if i am wrong :). Anyways, I am trying to use a windows tool which accepts the filepath as a parameter to capture screenshot. But the problem is that emacs is passing the filepath with "/" slash, but the tool is expecting "\". I have tried using (replace-regexp-in-string "/" "\" args) before call-process in the below code (code from org-screenshot.el), but it does not work. Any suggestion? Let me know if you need any more information regarding the same.

```
 (let* ((arglst (split-string org-screenshot-command-line " "))
         (cmd (car arglst))
         (scrpath (convert-standard-filename  (expand-file-name scrfilename)))
         (args (mapcar (lambda (x) (replace-regexp-in-string "%f" scrpath x))
                   (cdr arglst))))         
        (setq status (apply 'call-process cmd nil nil nil args))
        (unless prfx (make-frame-visible))
        (unless (equal status 0)
          (error "screenshot command exited with status %d: %s" status
             (mapconcat 'identity (cons cmd args) " ")) )
        (message "wrote screenshot to %s" scrpath))
      (org-display-inline-images nil t)))
```

Comment: solved the issue by creating a batch file which replaces / with \ and then calls the required program.